# Ayuda con este error en xamarin Forms

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, visual-studio-2017

[image: No me deja ejecutar mi aplicacion, alguien sabe porque me sale estas advertencias?]
Estoy trabajando con visual studio 2017

Comment: Intentaste Limpiar el proyecto y volver a compilar? ahí se nota que actualizaste la versión del xamarin pero no la aplicaste al proyecto.

Comment: pero al actualizar el xamarin forms se actualiza para todas? porque incluso he creado un nuevo proyecto desde cero y me siguen saliendo esas advertencias, y en los proyectos anteriores tambien salen esas advertencias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Entrando a las propiedades de tu proyecto puedes cambiar el Target Framework Version a la v7.1 que te exige tu compilador. [image]

Comment: gracias, funciona pero si lo quiero compilar en mi celular, tiene android 6.0 habrá algun problema?

Comment: No, porque le estableces un rango con el Minimun Android to target, (el combo de arriba).

Answer (score 0):

Esta utilizando una libreria que es android  v7.1 pero tu projecto esta hecho para android v6.0. Tienes que subirle la versión a tu projecto entrando la configuracion del mismo y si no lo tienes, descargalo por el sdk manager. De lo contrario tendras que buscar la libreria para v6.0.